# module 'vk' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vknet, vk-mini-apps

Использовал модуль нормально больше года, сегодня при установке в новом проекте он стал выдавать оишбку на до этого рабочем коде.

```
import vk
vk_Id = input()
token = "тут мой токен"
session = vk.Session(access_token=token)
vk_api = vk.API(session)
```

Ошибка: module 'vk' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: Если ваш файл называется vk.py, переименуйте его.

Comment: нет не называется.

Comment: Есть другие файлы/папки, которые так называются? Какой именно модуль устанавливаете для работы с vk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто пропускаешь момент с Session и сразу пишешь в  API свой токен

https://pypi.org/project/vk/